# Slideshow - link slide to URL only working for last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slideshow

I'm using lean slider: http://dev7studios.com/lean-slider/

I want to link each slide to a different url. I've noticed that only the code in the last slide gets executed (and also applied to all other slides).  For instance, adding an  tag to google on just the last slide results in all slides linking to google. Somehow, it only sees the very last slide - if you inspect element on the slide, you'll see it always highlights the last slide's code.

**EDIT:** I've also noticed that it works fine when you don't include the sample-style.css file. But without this, there is no fade/transition effect and the navigation buttons are not formatted, so it would be pointless without this file, but the issue is probably with how the slider works.

Any ideas on what's causing this or how to fix it?

The only thing changed - added links to each slide.  (index.html)

```
...
        <div id="slider">
            <div class="slide">
                <a href="http://www.yahoo.com" ><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide2">
                <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com" ><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide3">
                <a href="http://www.amazon.com" ><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide4">
                <a href="http://www.google.com" ><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```

Comment: You must provide the code you're using in order for us to be able and willing to help.

Comment: The code is pretty much the files in the slider download.  That's why I didn't include it, it would be too much and I don't even know which part is causing it, although I suspect its the javascript.

Comment: post the markup where you are adding the links

Answer (score 3):

I just figured it out. You should edit `z-index` property in these three places:

```css
.lean-slider-slide.current {
    z-index: 1;
}

#slider-direction-nav {
    z-index: 2;
}

#slider-control-nav {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

You can find it in `slider.css` and `sample-style.css` when you downloaded Lean Slider.

Comment: Don't know how you figured that out, but that's fantastic! Been trying to find the solution to this problem all day. +1 for you.

Comment: after almost an year..THANK YOU SO MUCH! :D

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on this **[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/3v56g/)**, it works perfectly even with external resources.

Things that you need to make sure you have:

1.Include jQuery library (jQuery MUST be included BEFORE lean-slider.js)

2.Include the lean-slider.js

3.Include the lean-slider.css

4.Make sure you have an auto_increment class on your images (slider1 , slider2, slider3, etc)

Below all these (not before) add this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').leanSlider();
});
```

And make sure the `div` that contains your images has an ID `id="slider"`

Comment: Your example doesn't include the links which was the problem I had to begin with. Moreover, you don't have the sample-styles.css that formats the navigation features, which when added, you will see the bug that I mentioned in my post.  (I have all the things you listed, it was already like that in the original code, which I didn't change except to add links.)

Comment: You never mentioned anything about the sample-styles.css,this got included after you edited your post...If you don't include everything on your initial post we can't just guess what you are trying to achieve or what your problem might be. Lean-slider works with opacity when you include the navigation control.That makes your links to be the 1 on top of the other,thats y only the last 1 work,as it has been loaded last-it sits on top of the others.You can try Nivo-slider if you want your images to be links and have an image navigation control,else you will need to make a lot of customizations

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation, that's what I couldn't figure out - why it sits on the top.  As for the sample-styles.css, I added it in later because I discovered it after I made the post, so I was updating my findings.

Answer (score 0):

Always take the last link; play with the css you can force the position of elements and enable the link for each image:

```
/*lean slider css overwrite*/
#slider-control-nav, #slider-direction-nav
{
 z-index:3;
}

.lean-slider-slide.current
{
 z-index:2;
}

.lean-slider-slide.current a
{
 float:left;
}
```